# python not work in terminal after upgrading

Tags: python, upgrade

recently I ungraded python version to 3.4, and found command "python" doesn't work in terminal, get "-sh: python: command not found". But "python3" or "python3.4" works well. I've added this into ~/.profie:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

System : OS X 10.9.3
Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Fixed. @Suku's answer helps a lot. Just reinstalled python 2.7.7, problem solved.
Thanks.

Comment: type `which python3` and for that same path you  can make an alias to python3 or whichever version you want, but this is not the usual way, you probably had multiple versions of  python. mention the paths of python install and the wrapper which calls python for  all the version

Comment: Do you want Python 3, or Python 2? Reinstalling Python 2 will obviously get you Python 2 as `python`. Linking Python 3 as `python` will get you Python 3 as Python. However, there is a reason that Python 3 has the command `python3` rather than `python`. This is because there are a number of incompatible changes between Python 2 and Python 3. Hence, you should not link `python` to refer to Python 3, because it will break things. You can have both installed at once, however. Just use `python` to refer to Python 2, and `python3` to refer to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"python" refers only to python 2.X; if you have only python3 installed on your computer then "python" will not work.

This is needed because python 3 introduces many backwards-incompatible changes. For example, in python 3, `print` is a function, not a statement. This necessitates access to the 2.X python for python 2.X applications.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. It really helps, I think I know how to fix this :))

Comment: something is "not a function not a statement." ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a soft link:

`ln -s $(which python3) python`

Comment: Thanks man. Actually I tried this before, but it didn't work for me, got "ln: python: File exists".

Comment: In that case, you don't have `python` in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: This will not work for the reasons outlined by @TheSquareCow (and also because doing it in a random directory does not make the link visible to the `PATH` unless you erroneously and insecurely have `.` on your path).  The system contains scripts which require `python` to refer to Python 2.